# Two very similar SQL statement, but one causes my HTTP Request Azure function to trigger and the other doesn't

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

In Azure Stream Analytics, I'm receiving telemetry from a sensor to the IoT Hub, and I'm outputting that to a C# Azure Function (HTTP Request type). The function sends an email with a warning.

The SQL query is

```sql
SELECT
   temp as value,
   time_of_reading as time
INTO
   warningFunction
FROM 
   input
WHERE 
   temp < 20
```

And the HTTP Request C# function is

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "SendGrid"
using System;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static SendGridMessage Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
    log.LogInformation(requestBody);
    var notifications = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Notification>>(requestBody);

    SendGridMessage message = new SendGridMessage();
    message.Subject = "Sensor Anomaly Warning";

    var content = "The IoT device has registered an anomaly.<br/><br/><table><tr><th>time</th><th>value</th></tr>";
    foreach(var notification in notifications) {
        log.LogInformation($" -  time: {notification.time}, value: {notification.value}");
        content += $"<tr><td>{notification.time}</td><td>{notification.value}</td></tr>";
    }
    content += "</table>";
    message.AddContent("text/html", content);  

    return message;
}

public class Notification
{
    public string time { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

This was copied from an [Azure tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-stream-analytics-query-patterns) and it works just fine.

Now I want to change the SQL code to output the temperatures (values) under some threshold over the last 5 measurements to trigger the email only in this case. So I change the SQL code to

```
SELECT
   temp as value,
   time_of_reading as time,
   device as device
INTO
   warningFunction
FROM 
   input
WHERE
   LAG(ec,5,-1) OVER (PARTITION BY device LIMIT DURATION(minute,10)) = -1
AND
   temp < 20
```

Indeed, running this with the "Test query" option, outputs the last 5 measurements under the threshold successfully. However, the C# function is not getting triggered anymore. I tested the function separately with the sample output of this SQL query, and it works fine. However, running the job with this SQL code won't trigger the function and send the email.

I troubleshooted this to the max. There are no error logs or weird stuff happening whatsoever. What's the matter?

Comment: You can't use Window functions in the `WHERE`; that latter query would error if run on SQL Server.

Comment: @Larnu How come? It's literally in the Azure Stream Analytics tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-stream-analytics-query-patterns).

Comment: That isn't for use against SQL Server though. I suppose my question there is, is this actually related to SQL Server?

Comment: @puradrogasincortar from the docs you linked: *Queries in Azure Stream Analytics are expressed in a SQL-like query language.* So, it is **not** valid t-sql .

Comment: @PeterBons But this tutorial is also using the LAG statement for this exact purpose (https://blog.sivamuthukumar.com/azure-stream-analytics-alerts-on-iot-telemetry). so what's the deal? If not with LAG, there must be a way to look back in the stream analytics input right?

Comment: A never mind, I think @larnu and I suspected you were using this query as input for an azure sql triggered azure function.

Comment: Perhaps asking a silly question here. Have you started the stream analytics job after saving the Query. "Test Query" shows you the result of the query, but it won't emit any events. Have you set any start options for the job. If a temporal operator is used (e.g. time window, LAG or JOIN), Azure Stream Analytics will automatically look back at the data in the input source. Please refer to the [Start options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/start-job#start-options) resource for more information.

Comment: LAG is used for looking back in the stream and is the right operator for this use case. Test query runs over a fixed set of input, there are some minor differences between test query and running job.

To debug this further
1. Move LAG from filter to SELECT, inspect the output and see if it is as expected. You can write to a blob storage.
2. Validate that output count metric is zero, to differentiate between query correctness and issue with azure function. 
Can expand the answer based on outcome from above.